# Embedding a MQL4 custom indicator code in an Expert Advisor

Tags: mql4

This is my first post on Stackoverflow although I've visited here for years.

I have read the message guidelines so I'll be as succinct and specific as possible.

> I have been attempting to embed the code of a Custom Indicator directly in an Expert Advisor without having to call iCustom:

```
iCustom(Symbol(),60,"MB",3D,0,1)>0;
```

Thus far I've failed and whilst I believe it is probably a trivial thing to do for many, if you don't know, you don't know.

The iCustom code in question is the following and I'd be grateful for any assistance:

```
#property indicator_chart_window

#property  indicator_buffers 2 
#property  indicator_color1 Blue
#property  indicator_color2 Red
#property  indicator_width1 5
#property  indicator_width2 5


extern int 3D= 5


double AIAIAI[];
double B1B1B1[];

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int init()
{
   SetIndexBuffer( 0, AIAIAI );
   SetIndexEmptyValue( 0, 0.0 );
   SetIndexStyle( 0, DRAW_ARROW );
   SetIndexArrow( 0, 250 ); 
   SetIndexLabel( 0, NULL );

   SetIndexBuffer( 1, B1B1B1);
   SetIndexEmptyValue( 1, 0.0 );
   SetIndexStyle( 1, DRAW_ARROW );
   SetIndexArrow( 1, 250 ); 
   SetIndexLabel( 1, NULL ); 

   IndicatorDigits( 5 );

   //---- name for DataWindow and indicator subwindow label
   IndicatorShortName( MB(" + 3D+ ")" );

   return( 0 );
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator deinitialization function                       |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int deinit()
{
   return( 0 );
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int start()
{
   int counted_bars = IndicatorCounted();

   if (counted_bars < 0) return (-1);
   if (counted_bars > 0) counted_bars--;
   int intLimit = Bars - counted_bars;
   int LO, HI;

   for( int NINI = intLimit; NINI >= 0; NINI-- )
   {          
      AIAIAI[NINI] = 0.0;
      B1B1B1[NINI] = 0.0;

      LO = iLowest( Symbol(), Period(), MODE_LOW, 3D, NINI );

      if ( LO == NINI )
      {
         AIAIAI[NINI] = Low[NINI];
      }

      HI = iHighest( Symbol(), Period(), MODE_HIGH, 3D, NINI );

      if ( HI == NINI )
      {
         B1B1B1[NINI] = High[NINI];
      }
   }

   return( 0 );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The best way to package the indicator code with the compiled EA is to include it as a resource and continue to call it using icustom. When you do it this way, there is no need to refactor and extract indicator logic.

The syntax is as follows:

```
#resource "MyCustomIndicator.ex4"

double my_custom_zero_buffer(string symbol, int period, int setting, int i)
{
   return iCustom(symbol, period, "::MyCustomIndicator.ex4", setting, 0, i);
}
```

When you compile this EA the Indicator will also be compiled and packaged together so you can use/distribute it without exposing the indicator logic

Comment: Thank you.  I've followed your instructions but unfortunately I receive the "cannot load resource" message in the journal.  I'll look online for more examples of using resources.

Comment: UPDATE:  I managed to get it to work.  Thanks again!!!   Can .DLLs be included as resources?

Comment: What value does my_custom_zero_buffer return? The custom indicator always seems to return 0. I'm attempting my first custom indicator and EA, but can't figure out how to get a value from the indicator to my EA.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the indicator as an example only, that is probably not a good indicator as it does not use buffers and overall very simple indicator. It should be quite easy to recompute the buffer value from the ea when you need it.

```
double iCustomValue(const int param,const int buffer,const int shift)
   {
    switch(buffer)
      {
       case 0:
          if(iLowest(_Symbol,0,MODE_LOW,param,shift)==shift)
              return iLow(_Symbol,0,shift);
          break;
       case 1:
          if(iHighest(_Symbol,0,MODE_HIGH,param,shift)==shift)
              return iLow(_Symbol,0,shift);
          break;
      }
    return(0.0);
   }
```

and use the function instead of your indicator. For more complicated indicators - keep in mind that calling indicators is slower of course but allows to test easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized and this should make sense that this works **only when the compiled indicator .ex4 file is in the same directory as the EA.** It seems to ignore the directory path, although I've gotten that the work before  where path = "c:\...\Indicators\mycustomindicator.ex4". I think it depends on the version of MT4 as there seems to be a variance in how that's treated.

Funny thing, the recommended approach doesn't work at all! Maybe for the same reason, not looking in the right place: looking at the **Experts** folder instead of the **Indicators** folder.

Neat trick, the resource thing!